# Are there any free application to automatically download album art-work for iTunes?

Tags: itunes, album-art

I want to download album art-work for my iTunes library without creating an iTunes store account.

There's an application called iArtwork that does just what I need but it is not free. Does anyone knows an alternative?

Note: I'm using Windows, so GimmeSomeTune won't work for me.

Comment: Why don't you want to create an iTunes account? They're free.

Answer (score 1):

[Soundcrank](http://www.soundcrank.com/download) sounds like it does that. It's a plugin for iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/). When you download the album artwork, save the artwork to the file. That way, iTunes will pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, I found Clutter to work really well, although that was a few years back.

I prefer doing things manually, and have found that the site [Album Art Exchange](http://www.albumartexchange.com/) to be the best site for great-looking (and expansive selection of) covers.

Answer (score 0):

[Songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/download/)

Seems like a good candidate